# previous_post_link in same taxonomy not working

Tags: wordpress

I have my cutom post taxonomy which is term_taxonomy_id (it's a reference to the ID of custom category of posts) and want to put prev/next post link but

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
next_post_link('%link','Next post',true,'','id');
endwhile; ?>
```

simply doesn't work (it doesn't show any code in result page).

After removing three last arguments:

```
next_post_link('%link','Next post');
```

there is no problem with showing the link though (but it's not in the same taxonomy of course which I'm not interested in).

Wordpress version is 3.8 of course.
Do you have any idea where the problem is?

Comment: are you on single post page?

Comment: 'id' is a taxonomy name?

Comment: term_taxonomy_id is the full name of the SQL column.

Comment: not so simple. If you want to follow DB, please find value of taxonomy column in _term_taxonomy_table. (is related to terms by term_id) and use it instead id

Comment: Thank you for the answer but I'm not really sure why should I do this? According to Codex http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/next_post_link the last argument should consist taxonomy's name. Am I right?

Comment: and this is exactly taxonomy name! (name of set of terms, like category)